# Is the DispersiveWiki website down?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, online-resources

Somewhat recently I learned about a website called the DispersiveWiki which is/was maintained by James Colliander. I have found a few different links to the website from around the web (e.g. [http://math.mit.edu/~gigliola/](http://math.mit.edu/%7Egigliola/) and https://terrytao.wordpress.com/ ) such as:

http://tosio.math.toronto.edu/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

https://kvm16.pims.math.ca/DispersiveWiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

https://dispersivewiki.org/DispersiveWiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

For a few weeks now I have been trying to access the DispersiveWiki without success – for all the links above, I have been getting an error message of ‘The website took too long to respond.’ I have tried this using various browsers and methods of connecting to the internet, and so I have begun to suspect that this may not be a problem on my end.

In summary, my questions are:

1. Do other people have difficulty accessing the website?
2. Is the DispersiveWiki still being maintained? If so, what is its current web address?

Comment: This does not seem like a question in research-level mathematics.

Comment: It is also down on my end, but I really don't think this question is appropriate.

Comment: it seems that the WayBackMachine has archived only [a single page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180810141609/https://dispersivewiki.org/DispersiveWiki/index.php?title=Davey-Stewartson_system) from that site, regrettably; since the DispersiveWiki was maintained (at least originally) by @TerryTao , perhaps that MO user knows more...